# Representing 1+1 Minkowski space as a surface in 3D Euclidean space

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, geometry, geodesics

In 1+1 Minkowski space the distance between two points is given by$$
(x_1 -x_2)^2 -(t_1 - t_2)^2.$$

This is different from the Euclidean distance. But is it possible to come up with a 2D surface embedded in 3D Euclidean space such that the geodesic distance between two points on the surface is like that in Minkowski space?

Comment: How could you hope to reproduce a negative distance square in a Euclidean space?

Comment: What about just the positive part? Or as two different surface one for inside the light-cone and one for outside it. (disregarding the negative sign in one case)

Comment: Interesting question. I have no idea. If negatives are forbidden, how about$ ((x_1 - x_2)^2 - (t_1 - t_2)^2)^2$. Also, is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_embedding_theorem related in any sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible because the induced metric on **any** submanifold $N$ of the Euclidean space $E^3$ is necessarily positively defined, whereas the metric on $1+1$ Minkowski space is indefinite.

The reason is trivial: The scalar product $\langle u,v\rangle $ of two vectors $u,v$ in  $N$ is, by definition, the scalar product in $E^3$ of these vectors viewed as vectors in $E^3$, so that $\langle u,u\rangle \geq 0$ -- where $\langle u,u\rangle=0$ implies $u=0$ -- in any cases, contrarily to what may happen in Lorentzian manifolds.